# Get the user's key from the firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have users data stored in the database

```
users: {
  -Kp56mwwpFiCwIXLszqu: {
     email: "testemail@gmail.com",
     name: "test name",
     username: "testname"
  },
  -Kp58X2WGUVNazSSbRqF: {
     email: "anotheruser@gmail.com",
     name: "another user",
     username: "anotheruser"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the user's key e.g. `-Kp56mwwpFiCwIXLszqu` or `-Kp58X2WGUVNazSSbRqF`.

I want to add more collections to the existing users. For eg. I am logged in as a `testname` and I want to get the `testname` key from the database, so that I can push more collections there.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These keys look like auto generated keys. You probably want to change the way of saving your user profile in the database by saving his data under his `uid`.

For example:

```
// Definition of the user profile class.
export class UserProfile {
    email: string;
    name: string;
    username: string;
}

----------------------------------------------------

// Inside of some service.
constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
) { }

saveUserProfile(profile: UserProfile): firebase.Promise<void> {
    let currentUserUid = this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    return angularFireDatabase.object(`users/${currentUserUid}`).update(profile);
}
```

That should save the user profile data under his `uid`. Notice that I used the `update` method instead of `push` because `push` generates a new unique key unlike the `update` or `set`. Your data will then have a structure like this:

```
users: {
    {user_uid_will_be_here}: {
        email: 'someone@example.com',
        name: 'Test User',
        username: 'myusername'
    }
}
```

You can then simply access to that data in the future by the currently logged user `uid`.

```
getCurrentUserProfile(): UserProfile {
    let currentUserUid = this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    return this.angularFireDatabase.object(`users/${currentUserUid}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked perfectly... I am now wondering why I didn't thought about that.. :)

Comment: @surazzarus No problem, glad I could help. :)